# Five months ago he was acquitted on a shop lifting charges

Tags: prepositions

Usually **acquit of** something is used.

Is it wrong if I say

> Five months ago he was **acquitted on** a shop lifting charges.

and what is different in

> Five months ago he was **acquitted of** a shop lifting charge.

Comment: Both are used and are idiomatic. [Check out the Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acquitted+on+charges%2Cacquitted+of+charges&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15).

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: I am not a legal expert, nor have I ever worked in the legal profession, so I am answering this question based on my understanding of English. I am happy for someone with a better understanding of law to correct my views.

Before addressing your question, I would like to correct your heading. A person can be acquitted of:

> a shoplifting charge,   (where charge is singular)

or

> (the) shoplifting charges,   (where charges is plural)

NOTE: In the above phrase 'the' is usually optional.

Most commonly we say that a person 'was acquitted **of** charges'. It is less usual to hear of someone who 'was acquitted **on** charges', however, this is heard often enough for me to regard it as an acceptable English expression. As far as I can see the two expressions mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing in practical terms —you can go free because you have been found innocent— but there is a subtle difference.

To be acquitted, you must be on trial for a charge and found not guilty.

To be **acquitted *of*** the charge is to be found innocent in respect to it, directly.

To be **acquitted *on*** a charge is to be found innocent in the proceedings where you were being tried on the charge.